# How to filter CM_Get_Device_Interface_List with GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK?

Tags: c, winapi

How can I call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` for `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK` type devices only? There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552153/how-to-find-the-com-port-number-of-a-modem-discovered-using-cm-get-device-interf), and the questioner's code is just type-casting it like:

```
LPGUID InterfaceClassGuid = (LPGUID)&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MODEM;
CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(InterfaceClassGuid, NULL, DeviceList, DeviceListLength, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);
```

This seems unlikely to work, and when I tried it, it gave me: argument of type "LPGUID" is incompatible with parameter of type "PCWSTR". The first parameter of `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` is type `PCWSTR` (a string), so I do not think `GUID` can be typecast to a string.

I have searched the web for "GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK" and "CM_Get_Device_ID_List", and there were almost no result but [this Japanese blog](http://morizzos-buglife.blogspot.com/2013/03/). The page does not show any code, but just had a paragraph describing the overall procedure. It says:

> Pass GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK to SetupDiGetClassDevs() to get the list of physical disks, and using SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo() for each disk, pass the disk's DEVINST to the CM_Get_Device_ID_List function with the flag of CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_REMOVALRELATIONS, you can get the list of the volume names on the disk.

I have tried calling `SetupDiGetClassDevs` and `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`, and the DEVINST values were just 1 and 2 (I have two disks on the computer). It does not seem like I could filter `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` with "1" and "2".

Damn, this is so very complicated and searching Google gives me few examples.

Comment: `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(const_cast<GUID*>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK), 0, .., CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT )` - in what problem do this call ?

Comment: look like you confuse `CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW` and `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`

Comment: @RbMm Yeah, right I was confused by "get device id list" and "get device interface list". I am new to this device-related programming, so all the concepts are confusing.